# Отключить анимацию блока

Tags: jquery, анимация

Есть сайт на wordpress, в его шаблоне была прописана функция на div `.wrap_one` анимация `fadeInUp`. Покопавшись в шаблоне, я нашел вот такую функцию:

```
jQuery('.wrap_one').each(function() {
    var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInUp");
    }
});
```

Подозреваю, что вопрос именно в ней. Нужно снять с этого блока функцию появления `div`-a после прокрутки колёсика мышки, можно просто убрать, но в идеале пусть он просто появляется сразу при загрузке страницы.

Помогите пожалуйста, что нужно изменить в коде?

Comment: просто выбери все элементы _fadeInUp_ - и удали этот класс

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в CSS свойтва класса fadeInUp и элеметнов к которым он применяется. Скорее всего там есть свойство `transition`. Переопределите его на `transition: none`

В крайнем случае, после `none` добавьте `!important`, но это лучше избегать. Постарайтесь указать более приоритетное правило CSS для блока без его использования.

`transition` - это свойство, которое отвечает за плавное именение свойств CSS

Answer (score 0):

Убрать следующее?

```
var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;
var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400)
      jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInUp");
```

Comment: Пробовал - блог и вовсе не показывается

Comment: не, ну смотри, блок сам по себе есть, ты в поле class указываешь wrap_one и он получает свои свойств, hover анимацию и другое(если есть), убери class вообще, и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: Если убираю, то слетают остальные атрибуты класса, переписать их под другой класс не получиться, так как это очень большой блок и там очень много h1, h2, и так далее, которые привязаны к данному классу